# Files from array not adding as multiple attachments in mail?

Tags: php, joomla, phpmailer

I've had some terrific assistance from one user in particular with regards to this issue, however, I have only one thing left to finalise and I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$path = JFolder::files(JPATH_SITE . '/tmp/containers/waybills');

echo '<form action="" method="post">';

foreach($path as $file){
   echo '<input name="fileName[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $file . '">' . $file . '<br>';

}

echo '<input name="send_email" type="submit" value="Send Email">';
echo '</form>';

if(isset($_POST['send_email']) && $_POST['send_email']){ 

  if(isset($_POST['fileName']) && $_POST['fileName']){ 

    if(count($_POST['fileName']) > 5){

      echo 'You can only select 5 files.';

      exit();

    }

$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$sender = array( 

    $config->get( 'mailfrom' ),

    $config->get( 'fromname' ) 

);

$mailer->setSender($sender);

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$recipient = $user->email;

$mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

$body   = "Test";

$mailer->setSubject('Testing');

$mailer->setBody($body);

foreach($_POST['fileName'] as $file2){ //should loop across the files again

      $mailer->addAttachment($file, $file2);  //This should add all the file's where I have ticked their respective checkboxes, as an attachment to the mail.
        }

 if(!$mailer->send()) { 

      echo 'Message was not sent.';

    } else {

      echo 'Message has been sent.';

    }

}else{

  echo 'No file was selected.';

  }
} 
?>
```

The message itself is sending no problem, it's only the attachments which are not being attached.

Comment: What are the values of the checkboxes? Are you simply assigning the filename or the filepath? You would need to provide the filepath in order for the mailer to add the attachment.

Comment: The values of the checkboxes are the names of the files being listed.

Comment: This code: `$path = JFolder::files(JPATH_SITE . '/tmp/containers/waybills');` lists all the files, so that is basically the file path.

Comment: Double check the value of `$mailer->addAttachment($file, $file2);` then.

Comment: `$file` will always be the last value of your first loop.]

Comment: This code is unsafe. Read the PHP docs on how to handle file uploads safely, and also see [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) for how to do this correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Synchro . That example is very good, I will be using that template I believe.

Comment: The only issue is that with Joomla PHP Mailer is already built in, and they use different syntax so it makes it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
foreach($path as $file){
   echo '<input name="fileName[]" type="checkbox" value="' . $file . '">' . $file . '<br>';

}
```

the name parameter remains as string as you are using a double quote.
You can make the following changes giving full path in value

```
$files = JFolder::files(JPATH_SITE . '/tmp/containers/waybills');
$path = JPATH_SITE . '/tmp/containers/waybills/'; //path to your files
echo '<form action="" method="post">';

foreach($files as $file){
   echo '<input name="' .$file. '" type="checkbox" value="' . $path.$file . '">' . $file . '<br>';
}
```

Remember all files should have a unique name.